# DNS Server is a strange Alpha-numeric jumble

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, port-forwarding

So I've been trying to port-forward my IP with 25565, but my router is seriously strange. From 3 sites and 2 programs, I have gathered that this information is vital:

IPv4:
25.0.187.9

Default Gateway:
2620:9b::1900:1
25.0.0.1

DNS:
fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1

Subnet Mask:
255.0.0.0

I notice that DNS and default gateway are... Strange as hell. This is exactly how they appear when I run cmd with ipconfig /all. According to my tutorials, they are meant to be normal numbers like my IP address... Any help?
Note that I have bound everything correctly according to two programs except changing my Local IP to Static (yet according to the internet I already did...) and I haven't added the ports to the firewall yet.

[image]

Comment: That looks like some kind of IPv6 addresses: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: Those pretty certainly are ipv6 addresses - I think having more information on your network topology is going to help

Comment: My default gateway is the same as my IPv6 address, know how to change that? It has the IPv4 underneath though... Any ideas about the DNS servers?

Answer (score 2):

These multicast IPv6 addresses are reserved for autodiscovery of DNS servers:

```
fec0:0:0:ffff::1
fec0:0:0:ffff::2
fec0:0:0:ffff::3
```

Moreover, the symbol `%1` identifies the first Ethernet interface.

See "[IPv6 Stateless DNS Discovery](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-ipngwg-dns-discovery-03.txt)" and "[Representing IPv6 Zone Identifiers in Address Literals and Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6874)".